# How to execute javascript once an update panel refreshes (Can't get Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(); to work)

Tags: ajax

using some date time picker plugins i am unable to rebind them after ajax update panel completion.
i used a control containing jquery plugins for date and time , inside page.
it works fine at first but when change drop down list, it's update panel rebind and don't bind jquery functionality again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is update panel refresh the dom and every child element inside update panel re-render when ajax request by update panel.

```
<script>
 function rebindJqueryPlugins() {
 jQuery('.example').datetimepicker();
 }
 if( typeof(Sys) != "undefined" )
 {
 prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
 Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function(){
 //rebinding elements with jquery plugins once we get reponse from server
 rebindJqueryPlugins();
 });
 }
 else
 {
 //we have a problem with ScriptManager
 }

//on page load calling jquery plugins to bind elements
jQuery (function(){
//console.log("najam is great");
rebindJqueryPlugins();
});
</script>
```